# Error: ':' is not a valid resource name character

Tags: android-studio, r.java-file

I have imported my eclipse project to android studio.I googled but not getting right answer.
These errors are occurred-

```
D:\***\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml
Error:Error: ':' is not a valid resource name character
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> D:\****\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml: Error: ':' is not a valid resource name character
```

My bulid gradle app code is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.******.***"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22
        multiDexEnabled true     }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories { mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-android-4.43.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-core-4.43.jar')
}
```

Please resolve my issue.
Thank you

Comment: Try to check your strings.xml file.

Comment: yes Vivek ,I can read and also change the specific notation.Still error occurred.

Comment: Those error types may occur when you try to run project without sync gradle.

Answer (score 12):

> Error: ':' is not a valid resource name character

means that you have a resource name like

```
<string name="not:valid">Foobar</string>
```

but colon are not allowed.

Try this:

- Open your `string.xml`
- Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (on Win/Linux)
- Check *Regex*  and search by `"[A-Za-z_]*:[A-Za-z_]*"`
- Remove colon and if necessary replace with an underscore `_`
- Compile your `apk`

Answer (score 7):

In my case there were a few layout unfortunately using ids of the form `"@id/android:foo"`. Turning them into `"@+id/foo"` solved the issue.

This happened when upgrading to AGP 3.3.

You can search for the regexp `="@\+[^"]*:[^"]*"` in your layout folder.

Comment: Yep, upgrading to AS 3.3 brought this one

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can't even have name like **break** because you will get similar error from compiler:

```
Error: break is not a valid resource name (reserved Java keyword)
```

Answer (score 0):

compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
I think you should try "-" instead of colon after design