# "Error: ':' is not a valid resource name character" after upgrading to Android Studio 3.3

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I keep developing an old Android project that I periodically update.
Now, after upgrading to Android Studio 3.3 I'm getting this error:

```
Error: ':' is not a valid resource name character
```

in the following res/layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="#4d4d4d">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/deleteAll">
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/favourite"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/fav"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deleteAll"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/yellow_button_event"
        android:text="@string/delete_fav" />        
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have found a lot of answers about that here on StackOverflow but none makes me to figure out what is the problem in my case.

Do you know what could be wrong with it?

Comment: I ran into a whole host of bad resource errors with 3.3.0. No combination of cleaning, invalidating caches, or deleting temporary folders would fix it. Unfortunately downgrading to 3.2.1 (in the project build.gradle) was the only thing that fixed it.

Comment: Maybe check your strings file as it could have some resource badly named with characters that should be scaped instead?

Comment: @FrancislainyCampos Do you means `strings.xml` file? Why should be there the problem if I see a given xml file in the log?

Comment: Yes, that's the strings.file. Sometimes errors of these kind come from that. And that's where we name the resources as well so that would be my guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
android:id="@+id/android:list"
```

This should be your error. Now unless your implementing some feature I am unfamiliar with, I understand this is bad naming convention. I assume this specific character wasn't being forced until 3.3

I would use..

```
android:id="@+id/list_favourite
```

Here is a [great website](https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2016/03/07/resourcenaming/) with various Android naming conventions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it doesn't work.

Comment: If that didn't work even after a clean/build, then I would remove each view/element, and slowly add them back to narrow down what line is specifically causing this.

Comment: Solved using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54495619/2516399 (that is similar to yours)